# Windows Explorer show file version OS wide / folder wide

Tags: windows, windows-explorer

I would like to see the file versions (i.e. of DLL's) but I have a lot of different folders/subfolders and turning the column 'file version' on in every folder is a bit undoable. Would it be possible to set a default for this somewhere?

Answer (score 0):

When you have the view you want in Explorer, go to `View`-->`Options` which should bring up *Folder Options*. In there you go to `View` and click on `Apply to Folders`.